# Opencart Session Variable Errors

Tags: php, session, variables, opencart

I'm having trouble sending data via sessions because I'm getting errors of undefined variable while defining the variable in controller/checkout/shipping_address.php under validate() function. (checkout/shipping_address/validate).

`$this->session->data['ship_date'] = $this->request->post['ship_date']; //<- line 102`

In controller/checkout/shipping_method

```
$ship_date = $this->session->data['ship_date'];
if(empty($ship_date)) echo "var empty";
$ship_date = explode("-", $ship_date);
$ship_date = $ship_date[0] . "/" . $ship_date[1] . "/" . $ship_date[2];
```

and then I do

```
$quote = $this->{'model_shipping_' . $result['code']}->getQuote($shipping_address, $ship_date);
```

Also yes, in model/shipping/fedex.php I allow usage of $ship_date parameter. Yet after that I get.

> Invalid JSON: **Notice**: Undefined index: ship_date in
>   **/var/www/catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_address.php** on
>   line **102**[] parsererror **Notice**: Undefined index:
>   ship_date in
>   **/var/www/catalog/controller/checkout/shipping_address.php** on
>   line **102**[]

Comment: So it is telling you all you need to know. "ship_date" is not existent in any of those two arrays.

Comment: @TobiasKun Can you add onto that?

Answer (score 1):

You should debug the arrays `$this->session->data` and `$this->request->post`.

The reason you see those errors is that there is no index `ship_date` in `$this->session->data` and in `$this->request->post`. So you get a `Notice: Undefined index:`.

Because of the notices that are printed your afterwards outputted json becomes invalid.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, OpenCart only talks through JSON. So adding this will help.

```
$JSONarray = array("date" => $this->request->post['ship_date']);
$this->session->data['ship_date'] = json_encode($JSONarray);
```

When you want to use it,

```
$JSONarray = $this->session->data['ship_date'];
$arr = json_decode($JSONarray, TRUE);
$Value = $arr['ship_date'];
```

We have to make the data JSON and then send it